# How to decode when the input of tracsaction consists of multiple contracts?

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, internal-transactions, decoding

I'm testing how to decode the input data of a transaction.
I am currently using Infura and web3py.

In the case of USDT token transfer, USDT ABI and contract address are obtained and decoded through Web3 as shown below.

tx_exam: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x10ae89504d616f7264d4e2685646df296bc0659faf25cf5cabea6dedf00a2a8b

```py
from ethereum_input_decoder import ContractAbi
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<project id>'))

#USDT 
ABI='[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_upgradedAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"deprecate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"deprecated","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_evilUser","type":"address"}],"name":"addBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradedAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balances","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"maximumFee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_maker","type":"address"}],"name":"getBlackListStatus","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newMaxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setParams","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"issue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"redeem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"basisPointsRate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"isBlackListed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_clearedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"removeBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_UINT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"destroyBlackFunds","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_decimals","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Issue","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Redeem","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"Deprecate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"feeBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"maxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Params","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_balance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DestroyedBlackFunds","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"AddedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"RemovedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"}]'
contract_addr = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7
tx_addr = 0x72c43755a8a1c8855fe05b5f5e8ac8486d86fd7592d4df299f702c9438596f99
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=ABI)
info = w3.eth.get_transaction(tx_addr)
print(f'info : {info}')

input = contract.decode_function_input(info.input)
print(f'input: {input}')
```

result:

```
info : AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0xeb6645b7f457652f5659c132d5730923e7a426cf5082e9360effb0fc6f3a8874'), 'blockNumber': 12907292, 'from': '0x5BCCB9eAb6059cc6aA779b30CEB4Ab9753Af9eD1', 'gas': 65000, 'gasPrice': 30000000000, 'hash': HexBytes('0x72c43755a8a1c8855fe05b5f5e8ac8486d86fd7592d4df299f702c9438596f99'), 'input': '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000efab108724ce581a0373d6f2e70b5e1d08619037000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140d06b', 'nonce': 14062, 'r': HexBytes('0x0aed3f1f217ed8b9b01338a201898346f7d79ecdf30ec1e0b0ed57a569102276'), 's': HexBytes('0x587fb3c7691342d64ec7c1f12ea774c65da02009d2e017286324d3e87334e264'), 'to': '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7', 'transactionIndex': 486, 'type': '0x0', 'v': 38, 'value': 0})
input: (<Function transfer(address,uint256)>, {'_to': '0xEfAb108724Ce581a0373d6F2E70B5e1d08619037', '_value': 21024875})
```

But,Some tx have complex Transferred as below...
exam: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2cc680e68bf16b6b2cd354afc4f4ddaf6ac8c9eb26ae249245d958c68300d750
[image]

In the case of Etherscan, decoding is performed as follows...
How can I decode in this case?
Which contract's ABI should I use..?
[image]

Is the transfer between tokens different from normal transactions?
Please inquire whether there is a separate transaction hash for transmission or whether it can be checked.

Is the debug_tracetransaction of geth a function to trace this transfer?
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decode from the input whether the smart contract is going to call other smart contracts. The only way to find out this is to execute the transaction in a node and take a trace what the smart contract is doing.

> Is the debug_tracetransaction of geth a function to trace this transfer?

Yes.